# what happens to the rendering engine in chrome when the browser download CSS files?

Tags: css, google-chrome

what happens to the parsing process of html file in chrome when the browser goes and download CSS files?
many options can happen and cannot understand what exactly will happen ?

(1)**First option:** when rendering engine in chrome sees the CSS files something will go and download it and the rendering will stop parsing and do nothing until the download is finished then there are two options:

a)the engine will start to parse the CSS files and after  finishing from css it will continue to parse html and rendering it ?

b)after finishing the download the engine will back to html again and after finishing parsing it it will back to the css.

(2)**Second option:** the download will not affect the parsing of html it will continue to parse html while downloading is happening in the background and when the download is finished there are two options may happen:

a) engine will continue to parse html and then back to the downloaded css after finishing from the html?

b) engine will parse css as soon as it comes leaving the rest of html after finishing css?

Comment: Which HTML parser?

Comment: I mean the render engine reading the html file in general whatever the detailed steps happening during parsing

Comment: Which one? There are lots.

Comment: i dont know if i understand your question well but if you mean different browsers do different things lets choose chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following happens in Chromium:

CSS files, like any other files loaded through a `<link>` element won't affect the parser. The parser will continue and simultaneously send out a GET request to fetch the requested source.
The CSS is parsed by the main thread, but this is done after the HTML is parsed.

Comment: so chrome when the download of css finished it will be reading both html and css at the same time ?

Comment: also isnt V8 Engine only for javascript ?

Comment: At that time the HTML will be parsed first, after that the CSS will be parsed. Only the download of CSS files happens concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for you help Keimeno very much.
if you can please answer my last question.
this is different from JS files as scripts will block the parsing during download also is that right ?

Comment: If JS scripts have the `defer` attribute (which by default is enabled) they will block the parsing process, until the JS file is fetched (either from the network, or from the local cache), parsed, and executed. However, you can add the `async` attribute to `<script>` tags, this will treat them like CSS files.

Comment: okay this is now clear for me. Thanks Keimeno very much for you great help.